# Call an activity only once in the app and show it again when the app restart after being killed

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I'm developing an application in which I have to show an activity only once in the app lifecycle.

What I'm doing is on my `MainActivity.java` I'm calling an `Activity 1`, so after when I move in my app and whenever I come back to `MainActivity.java` my `Activity 1` is called. I just want to show it once.

And again `Activity 1` should be displayed when user kills the app and restarts it.

Here is what I'm doing in my `MainActivity.java`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                Activity1.class));

    }
```

I have tried using the following code but it only run once, when the app is installed for the first time.

```
private boolean isFirstTime() {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean ranBefore = preferences.getBoolean("RanBefore", false);
    if (!ranBefore) {
        // first time
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("RanBefore", true);
        editor.commit();
    }
    return !ranBefore;
}
```

How can I modify the above code, so that my requirement is satisfied.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean once in the app life cycle or once when the user starts the app for the first tine, and never again?

Comment: Once only the users starts the app I want to show the activity. If the user is moving in my activity and he came to MainActivity I don't want to show Activty1 again to the user. And, when user exits the app and again restarts the app then again Activity1 will be shown again not showing Activity1 until and unless he exits the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem using `SharedPreferences`. What I have done is on Splash I entered some values in `SP`, and on the `MainActivity` I checked that, if the value matches show the activity, otherwise don't open the dialog. And on `keyCodeBack()`, I have cleared `SP`, this helps me in meeting my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
return !ranBefore
```

to

```
return ranBefore
```

It looks to me that you are always returning the same thing instead of the variable you initialize. Also, you could put the code to start the `Activity` directly in that method. Then you don't have to even worry about a `return` statement. It will just never run it again after you change the value in `SharedPreferences`

**Edit**

you can set your `SharedPreferences` value to false in `onCreate()`. This will work if you don't finish your `Activity` when you go to another and if its your main `Activity` then you probably don't ever want to finish it until you exit the app

Comment: Changed this, but didn't solve my problem. Still same scenario is coming up.

Comment: I just want to show the Activity1 once until and unless the app is closed. Regardless of how many times user comes to MainActivity. And when user after exiting the app again restarts it again show him Activity1 and then don't him until and unless he is in the app. Did you get my question?

Comment: Still not working for me. I have tried it doing Force Stop also, but no success. After doing force stop my Activity1 should again appear but no, it is not appearing.

Comment: Can you explain me whatever you are saying via code? I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `ranBefore` to false in `onDestroy`

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() 
{
    SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("RanBefore", false);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: How to set `ranBefore` to false? and where should I put the above code inside `private boolean isFirstTime()` or ` if (!ranBefore)`?

Comment: The codes above set ranBefore to false, put those codes in onDestroy()

Comment: This did not work for me. Again it is repeating itself after I have closed my app and navigating it to another activity to mainactivity, the intent is passed.

Comment: What do you mean by closing your app? when you closed your app isn't the app life cycle is done?

Comment: Ya the life cycle for the app is over. But again repeating my prm in different way. I just want to show the `Activity1` once until and unless the app is closed. Regardless of how many times user comes to `MainActivity`. And when user after exiting the app again restarts it again show him `Activity1` and then don't show him until and unless he is in the app. Did you get my question?

Comment: Does your app start with MainActivity? If it is then onDestroy is called only when the app is closed or the OS killed the activity (onDestroy may not even be called).

Answer (score 0):

Use shared preferences..

and to kill the activity, use class.finish() at  your onClick()..